# No passwd entry for user 'hdfs'

Tags: hadoop, hive, google-compute-engine

I trying to set up a hive environment on my google compute engine hadoop clusters which was deployed from one click deployment.

When I try to switch to hdfs user(su hdfs), I get below error message.

**No passwd entry for user 'hdfs'**

Comment: You should probably add something to your question to explain why you expect the user 'hdfs' to exist. Is that user mentioned in the documentation of the one click deployment?

Answer (score 0):

The "one-click deployment" is an older sample which perhaps showcases installation from shell scripts and tarballs, but isn't intended for use as a supported Hadoop service, and doesn't set up typical Hadoop installation configurations like an `hdfs` user or adding commands to `/usr/bin`.

If you want a more Hadoop (and Pig+Hive+Spark) specialized service, you may want to consider using [Google Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/), which is Google's managed Hadoop solution. You can [create clusters from the cloud console UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/dataproc/clusters) in Dataproc just like click-to-deploy, and you'll get a more fully installed Hadoop/Hive environment, including a per-cluster persistent MySQL-based Hive metastore which is shared with SparkSQL to make it easy to play with Spark without modifying your Hive environment if you so choose.